# Adding a File object programatically in Plone using PloneFormGen

Tags: action, adapter, plone, ploneformgen

I'm writing a PloneFormGen custom action adapter in order to add a File object to a folder from the File Field in the form. Here is the script:

```py
target = context.filefolder   
form = request.form    
uid = str(DateTime().millis())

target.invokeFactory("File", id=uid, file=form['arquivo-do-cv_file'])

obj = target[uid]
```

"filefolder" is the name of a folder inside the parent folder for the PFG FormFolder. This script is configured to run with a Manager proxy role.

Problem is that the File objects created this way won't show the "Click here to download the file" link when I view them. The files can be downloaded though, if I suppress the "/view" part from the end of the URL. What am I missing when calling invokeFactory to create the File object?

UPDATE: What I meant is that I don't get the **"*filename* - *filetype*, *size in KBs* (*size in bytes*)**" link for the document, below the byline. When I create a File object using the normal Plone UI, it does show up.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect nothing; I think that is the default behavior in Plone 4.

I just added a File and I don't see any "Click here to download the file".

[image]

And a quick search does not reveal the string "click here to download":

```
aclark@Alex-Clarks-MacBook-Pro:~/Developer/test-4.1/ > grep -ir "Click here to download" parts/omelette
parts/omelette/plone/app/jquerytools/browser/jquery.tools.plugins.js:                   (root.tagName == 'A' ? "<p>Click here to download latest version</p>" : 
parts/omelette/plone/app/jquerytools/browser/jquery.tools.plugins.min.js:" or greater is required</h2><h3>"+(g[0]>0?"Your version is "+g:"You have no flash plugin installed")+"</h3>"+(a.tagName=="A"?"<p>Click here to download latest version</p>":"<p>Download latest version from <a href='"+k+"'>here</a></p>");if(a.tagName=="A")a.onclick=function(){location.href=k}}if(b.onFail){var d=b.onFail.call(this);if(typeof d=="string")a.innerHTML=d}}if(i)window[b.id]=document.getElementById(b.id);f(this,{getRoot:function(){return a},getOptions:function(){return b},getConf:function(){return c},
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Plone instance to test it, but try to call `processForm()` after `invokeFactory`. It will:

- unmark creation flag;
- rename object according to title;
- reindex the object;
- invoke the after_creation script and fire the ObjectInitialized event.

These actions are detailed on [Object Construction Lifecycle](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/creating.html#oject-construction-life-cycle). Maybe some of these actions are needed to create the KB information you're after (I'm hoping it's the index).